# cannot run the cmd from su - <user>

Tags: java, bash, jboss

I've tried to connect to JBoss from jboss user (current user - root) using such cmd:

```
protected static final String CONNECT = "--connect";
protected static final String EXECUTOR = "/bin/jboss-cli.sh";
protected static final String CONTROLLER = "--controller";
protected static final String SU_CMD = "su";
protected static final String SHELL_FLAG = "-c";


protected static final String COLON = ":";
protected final static String SPACE = " ";
protected final static String QUOTE = "\"";
protected final static String DASH = "-";

public String[] getCommandWithController(String serverPath, String server_path, String server_port) {
        String[] cmd = {SU_CMD, DASH, JBoss.getUsername(), SHELL_FLAG, serverPath + EXECUTOR + SPACE + CONNECT + SPACE + CONTROLLER + "=" + server_path + COLON + server_port, this.getCommand()};
        return cmd;
    }
```

So for `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(anCmdArr)` it will look like:

**su - jboss -c /jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:10999 :read-resource(recursive=true, recursive-depth=10, include-runtime=true)**

But my console's hangs. At the same time, If I run it manually it will work:

```
# su - jboss -c "/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:10999"

[standalone@localhost:10999 /] :read-resource(recursive=true, recursive-depth=10, include-runtime=true)
```

I think the problem in the cmd. I've tired quotes, string concatenation like:

1)

```
String[] cmd = {SU_CMD + SPACE + DASH + SPACE + JBoss.getUsername() + SPACE + SHELL_FLAG + QUOTE + serverPath + EXECUTOR + SPACE + CONNECT + SPACE + CONTROLLER + "=" + server_path + COLON + server_port + QUOTE, this.getCommand()}
```

That will look like:

**su - jboss -c "/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:10999"**

2)

```
String[] cmd = {SU_CMD, DASH, JBossTaskConstants.getUsername(), SHELL_FLAG, QUOTE + serverPath + EXECUTOR + SPACE + CONNECT + SPACE + CONTROLLER + "=" + server_path + COLON + server_port + QUOTE, this.getCommand()};
```

Looks:

**su - jboss -c "/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:10999" :read-resource(recursive=true, recursive-depth=10, include-runtime=true)**

But all I could get was:

```
error = 2, No such file or directory
```

Ex.:
Error message: :read-resource(recursive=true, recursive-depth=10, include-runtime=true): /jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:10999: No such file or directory

What can I change?

Comment: Did you perhaps forgot the double quotes?

Comment: Another possibility is, that your java code is trying to execute this command in its java working directory instead of your desired working directory, since you're using relative paths.

Comment: @dnsiv 
**/usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh** is the absolute path. Are you talking about this path?

Comment: did you try using that absolute path yet?

Comment: @dnsiv yes, I can connect when run this cmd manually.

Comment: No, what I mean is this: If you run your Java program, you will get a different working directory than the current directory, in which you're typing the command into CMD. You should print out `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to see, if you're working in the same working directory as that one, which you're in, when you're typing that command of yours manually.

Comment: So if `System.getProperty("user.dir")` doesn't return `/usr/share/`, which actually is your desired working directory, that means, you need to change your current working directory in your java code or use an absolute path instead of that relative path of yours.

Comment: @dnsiv I tried `System.getProperty("user.dir")` and run cmd manually from that directory. The situation's repeated. Also I don't understand how it can help.  Since all variables (LAVA_HOME, JBOSS_HOME, ...) are global (identical for root and jboss users) and cmd uses only one path (and it's absolute). root and jboss have enough permissions to run that cmd.

Comment: @dnsiv I've edited the question. **/usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh** is not the absolute path. => **/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh** now

Answer (score 1):

When we uses **-c** parameter bash expects only one command. Therefore, my old cmd was wrong, because it consists of two separate cmds:

1. **/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:10999** command was send to *jboss* sessions.
2. But **:read-resource(recursive=true, recursive-depth=10, include-runtime=true)** was just a parameter for *root* session.

So I should send 1 and 2 like one parameter to -c option. I've deleted a comma and 
escaped a 2cmd into the quotes:

```
String[] cmd = {SU_CMD, DASH, JBossTaskConstants.getUsername(), SHELL_FLAG, serverPath + EXECUTOR + SPACE + CONNECT + SPACE + CONTROLLER + "=" + server_path + COLON + server_port + SPACE + "\'" + this.getCommand() + "\'"};
```

what is a:

**su - jboss -c /jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:10999 ':read-resource(recursive=true, recursive-depth=10, include-runtime=true)'**

To run it manually double quotes should be used, since single quotes have a higher priority:

**su - jboss -c "/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:10999 ':read-resource(recursive=true, recursive-depth=10, include-runtime=true)'"**